# Changing Passwords PHP

Tags: php, passwords, md5

How can I allow a change of password with md5 in mind.  When the accounts are being created the passwords are being entered in md5.  So now when i display the password field of course they are in md5 (don't worry for testing purposes i am showing the password in the field instead of displaying hashes or dashes).

So how do i go about changing the passwords then? When they are changed they also need to be in md5.

Comment: Why are you displaying anything in the password field in the first place?

Comment: There's a good tip of using sha1 instead of md5. md5 can be decrypted 64000 times easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't display anything in the password field.  Have 3 fields.  One for the original password (for security), and 2 for the new password (one for verification).

When submitted, check the old password, if it's right, md5 the new one and save it.

Answer (score 2):

In the database you overwrite the old MD5 hash with the new MD5 hash. Or are you asking a user interface question?

Answer (score 2):

The MD5 hash is a one-way hash that cannot be decrypted, so there's no need to display it. Changing the passwords updates the database with a new MD5 hash.

Answer (score 1):

## So how do i go about changing the passwords then?

I think you should read [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)
(Article from author stackoverflow.com):

> We learned that in a password hashing
> scheme, speed is the enemy. We learned
> that MD5 was designed for speed. So,
> we learned that MD5 is the enemy.

If you must store your passwords(Please also read below for more tips) use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to store your passwords securely. I advice you to read the article on the site explaining [How to manage a PHP application's users and passwords](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords). It will teach you how to do it securely using email verification tokens.

Just for the fun of it I also created a library(please also read below) which does this for you using the excellent phpass. It is hosted at [github](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-auth) and you can take a look at it if you like. Especially you should have a look at [Authentication Class](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-auth/blob/master/lib/Authentication.php) together with [AuthenticationTest](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-auth/blob/master/lib/test/AuthenticationTest.php).

## OpenID

Furthermore I would like to point out you should use something like OpenID, Facebook Connect, Google Friend Connect instead. You should not be storing your passwords because it is risky business like [The Dirty Truth About Web Passwords](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html) explains.

Jeff Atwood:

> I'm not here to criticize Gawker. On
> the contrary, I'd like to thank them
> for illustrating in broad, bold relief
> the dirty truth about website
> passwords: we're all better off
> without them. If you'd like to see a
> future web free of Gawker style
> password compromises -- stop trusting
> every random internet site with a
> unique username and password! Demand
> that they allow you to use your
> internet driver's license -- that is,
> your existing Twitter, Facebook,
> Google, or OpenID credentials -- to
> log into their website.

I also have a nice [OpenID library](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid) available at github which uses LightOpenID with openid-selector. You can see a demo up and running at my shared hosting provider: http://westerveld.name/php-openid/